# Why is my first div outside of the window?

Tags: html, css, angular, responsive, angular-flex-layout

I'm just trying the FlexLayout for different screen sizes.
The 3 boxes/divs below should be side to side on a large display, if it shrinks they should be above each other. But my top div is outside of my window and I don't want that.. How can I fix that?

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
  <div class="asd" [style.background-color]="'black'"></div>
  <div class="asd" [style.background-color]="'green'"></div>
  <div class="asd" [style.background-color]="'blue'"></div>
</div>
```

```
.asd {
  min-height: 500px;
  min-width: 400px;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `min-width: 400px;`? You might consider using flex children properties and percentage based widths instead.

Answer (score 0):

Flex elements won't stack unless you use `flex-wrap: wrap` along with a `min-width` or `flex-basis` declaration.

Basically, if the number of flex elements in the row would need to be smaller than their min-width they'll wrap to the next line.

```css
.flexContainer {
   display:flex;
   max-width: 80%;
   margin: 20px;
   
   justify-content: space-between;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flexItem {
   background: #dddddd;
   padding: 20px;
   min-width: 200px;
   margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="flexItem">Flex</div>
  <div class="flexItem">Flex</div>
  <div class="flexItem">Flex</div>
  <div class="flexItem">Flex</div>
</div>
```